# Подсчёт символов в строке C#

Tags: c#, winforms

Подсчитывается относительная частота встречаемости каждого символа в тексте.
К примеру в textBox1 записывается "A B". После в Form2(к примеру) в ложенный в него textBox будут записываться A-50%, B-50%.

Comment: Dictionary вам в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```cs
string test = "здесь текст из контрола"; // textBox1.Text

var counted = test
    .GroupBy(c => c)
    .Select(g => new { g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(o => o.Count);

foreach (var res in counted)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1} [{2}%]", res.Key, res.Count, 100.0 / test.Length * res.Count);
}
```